# Convert Date format from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert Date format from mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in javascript. I tried below code getting Invalid date.

```
var convertJSDate = function(dateTime)
        {
            var dateTime = dateTime.split(" ");

            var dateArr = dateTime[0].split("-");
            //var timeArr = dateTime[2].split(":");
            var date1= new Date(dateArr[2],dateArr[0],dateArr[1],0,0,0,0);
            return date1;
        }

var startTime = convertJSDate("06-08-2015");
```

Here, I want to display the startTime as `2015-06-08 00:00:00`. Now I am getting `return date1` as `Invalid date`. I don't know where is the issue.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code, like that it should work:

```
var convertJSDate = function(dateTime)
        {
            var dateArr = dateTime.split("-");
            var date1= new Date(dateArr[2] + "-" + dateArr[0] + "-" + dateArr[1]);
            return date1;
        }

var startTime = convertJSDate("06-08-2015");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have edited my question.  I need the result in  "2015-06-08 00:00:00"  format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the date in JavaScript, you may consider using **moment.js**.

http://momentjs.com/

Based on what I see from the documentation, the library may awesomely fit your need. With moment.js you can format Date like in C#:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 8th 2015, 8:15:34 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Monday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jun 8th 15
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');
```

Above are excerpt from moment.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Format any date in YYYY-MM-DD format in Javascript

```
let date = (fecha) => {
  let f = fecha.split('T')
  let nf = (f[1] !== undefined) ? [f[0], f[1].slice(0,10)].join(' ') : f;
  let d = new Date(nf)
  
  let q = d.toLocaleString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).split('/')
  let s = d.toLocaleString('en-US', { second: 'numeric',hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true })

return [q[2],q[0],q[1]].join('-') +' '+ s;
}

console.log(date('2019-01-09T11:43:05.000+00:00'))
```